# In webiste live chat is there any chance to track data

Tags: networking, webserver, website, chat

If I open some website **(both wired and wireless)** online live chat comes up. Like this,

Hi Friend, How can I help you?

When I chat with them is there any chance to track or get data from PC .

**How can I find particular website chat is safe or unsafe.**

Comment: What do you mean by track? Are you referring to your or their PC? Sounds like an advertisement?

Comment: I mean track as taking data in my pc without my knowledge.

Comment: Which is not what tracking usually refers to. What tracking usually means is identifying you across multiple visits to (different) websites possibly even with different bowers/across multiple browser sessions. Most browsers don't allow local access to data but with Plugins like Flash/Silverlight/Java there might be some possibilities. There is always a possibility of exploits hat could exist. Best way is to use your own judgment and make sure it's a reputable site/service offering the chat.